# How to read remote registry with winreg on Node.js and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using winreg through npm to read my local registry, and all is working well.

However, I do need to read remote registry also. Does anyone know if this can be done with winreg, or can suggest an alternative?

I have heard of doing it through WMI as well. Will this be possible through JavaScript?

Comment: What remote registry?

Comment: I have a specific "connectionstring" i am reading from the registry, however, i need to read this from another machine (server). It is under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\ etc..